# Get List of all user journey

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, tracking

I want to create a report where I want to get the list of all user identified, pages views count, all the pages views by user and timestamp.

Please suggest the best way to track user journey.

Comment: Your answer is going to be very similar tor the answer I gave here. All the fields you have requested are in the sitecore_analytics_index. You just need to make a call and gather the data you need. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7249/where-to-find-visit-duration-and-latest-date-visited-in-code-behind/7261#7261